# Modifying an imageDatastore without restoring the images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, deep-learning, rgb, grayscale

I am using an `imageDatastore` containing the labels and grayscale images for a deep learning classification problem. I want to fine tune `alexnet` on my dataset but it accepts RGB images.

How can I modify the `imageDatastore` without storing them again assuming that I just want to concatenate the grayscale image in 3 channels?